# Android: Creating storage array for enemies

Tags: java, android, class, arraylist, opengl-es-2.0

I have a ArrayList for dynamically creating enemies in a game. When populating the list intuitively, the game crashes suddenly, presumably with a null pointer exception.

The array is declared as such:

```
...
 ArrayList<EntityPlayer> EnemyList;
```

and populated with the enemy contents:

```
...
EnemyList.add(new EntityPlayer(mMVPMatrix, mActivityContext, R.drawable.enemy));
```

Suddenly, at this point, the program crashes with log:

```
03-30 01:03:02.066: W/dalvikvm(1348): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6185908)
03-30 01:03:02.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 102
03-30 01:03:02.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 01:03:02.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.example.rr.ApplicationClass.GLRenderClass.onDrawFrame(GLRenderClass.java:143)
03-30 01:03:02.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
03-30 01:03:02.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

The goal of this is to spawn a new enemy in an "if" statement, and use the methods stored in the element's instantiation of `EntityPlayer`. I can declare separate instances of EntityPlayer manually, but I have better control in this system. (Which is meant to mimic a vector class in C++)

Comment: Try to follow Java naming conventions. Use 'mixedCase' for methods/variables and use 'CamelCase' for classes/interfaces.

Comment: You never initialized EnemyList

Comment: Thanks @Tyler:  Initializing the `ArrayList<>` resolved the problem. You can post as answer.

Comment: @Christian: You're right, sometimes I run through personal code like scrap paper to get an implementation. But it gets cleaned up afterwards. I'll take this as a friendly warning though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ArrayList<EntityPlayer> EnemyList;` to 
`ArrayList<EntityPlayer> EnemyList = new ArrayList<EntityPlayer>();`